# Is there a way to control Emission values using an empty's movement?

Tags: shaders

I want to animate the brightness of an object using an empty's movement, or something like this. I don't see any ability to animate (directly) the shader attributes in the dope sheet / timeline, but I've seen other elements changed (UVMap Projector) using any object.

Is this possible?

I've searched Google and either couldn't figure out the right keywords, or couldn't find documentation on this.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can animate the shader emission attribute directly. You can just hover over the attribute you want to animate and press i or right click on it and click Insert keyframe https://i.imgur.com/DVfYn01.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate emission with an empty movement you can use driver. To create it, click with right mouse button on numeric field of Strength property of the shader, choose Add Driver>Manually Create Later (Single). Then open Graph Editor, change mode from F-Curve to Drivers, click on one of frames on the curve you'll see, go to properties panel on the right (press N if closed), go to Driver, choose Scripted Expression as Type, in Expr window type var,for Object choose Empty, and for Type and Space choose X Location (or Y or Z, doesn't matter), World Space and done. Check gif below to see the process.
[image]

Comment: Could you maybe use some formating in this answer like list for steps, cursive/bold for key features or something? It is really hard to fallow along with it (for me).

Comment: Sorry @LukeD, no time for aesthetics, but I see you have enough reputation score to edit it, so be my guest.

Comment: @Mzidare just make it when you will have time.

Comment: Ok  @LukeD, no problem.